# get all the users within X KM range from a user

Tags: javascript, haversine

I have an array of users and their gps coordinates.
what formula can I use to get all the users that are within X KM range
from a user?

I need to avoid heavy calculations.
I was thinking about sorting the array, but I realized that it isn't a good idea, because I would have to set a sorted array for each user.

Comment: Are you looking for a heuristic to avoid having to use the Haversine formula on every user? Have you tried doing that and determined that it's too slow? Because Haversine really isn't a "heavy calculation".

Comment: Haversine formula is like this: haversine(lat1,lon1, lat2,lon2)                           I want a function in this form: function(lat1,lon1, XKM).  I do want to use Haversine formula if it's possible in this form.

Comment: but i realy prefer a solution that wont force me run on all users in the array.

Comment: It should really be okay to run against every user. I tested the function I posted below and I can run it against an array of 100,000 users in 27 miliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Haversine formula to find the users that are within a specified distance from a specified point:

```
function getNearbyUsers(lat, lng, distanceInKm, users) {
    var R = 6373;

    var latRad = lat * Math.PI/180;
    var lngRad = lng * Math.PI/180;

    var returnUsers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var lat2Rad = users[i].lat * Math.PI/180;
        var lng2Rad = users[i].lng * Math.PI/180;
        var dlat = lat2Rad - latRad;
        var dlng = lng2Rad - lngRad;
        var a  = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat/2),2) + Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(lat2Rad) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlng/2),2);
        var c  = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a),Math.sqrt(1-a)); // great circle distance in radians
        var d = c * R; // Distance from user in km

        if (d < distanceInKm) returnUsers.push(users[i]);
    }

    return returnUsers;
}
```